# Pythonic sentence splitting on words starting with capital letter

Tags: python, string, split

I have couple of sentences in UTF that I want to split based on first capital letter.

Examples:

`"Tough Fox" -> "Tough", "Fox"`

`"Nice White Cat" -> "Nice", "White Cat"`

`"This is a lazy Dog" -> "This is a lazy", "Dog"`

`"This is hardworking Little Ant" -> "This is hardworking", "Little Ant"`

What is pythonic way to do such splitting?

Comment: Typo in #2 or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: What if the first letter in the string isn't in caps?  Would `"this Is a lazy Dog" -> "this", "Is a lazy", "Dog"`

Comment: So the first capital letter that isn't at the start of the sentence?

Comment: @Krumelur No - it's not a typo.

Comment: OK, I'll update my answer then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to split a string on each capital letter following a whitespace

```
import re

s = "Tough Fox"
re.split(r"\s(?=[A-Z])", s, maxsplit=1)

['Tough', 'Fox']
```

The `re.split` method is equivalent to the Python builtin `str.split`, but allows a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to be used as split pattern.

The regex first looks for a whitespace (`\s`) as the split pattern. This pattern will be eaten by the `re.split` operation.

The `(?=...)` part tells is a read-ahead predicate expression. The next character(s) in the string must match this predicate (in this case any capital letter, `[A-Z]`). However, this part is not considered part of the match, so it will not be eaten by the `re.split` operation.

The `maxsplit=1` will make sure that only one split (maximum two items) occur.

Answer (score 3):

I would use re:

```
>>> import re
>>> l = ["Tough Fox", "Nice White Cat", "This is a lazy Dog" ]
>>> for i in l:
...   print re.findall("[A-Z][^A-Z]*", i)
... 
['Tough ', 'Fox']
['Nice ', 'White ', 'Cat']
['This is a lazy ', 'Dog']
```

Edit:
Okay, I thought that was a mistake. So now I am a little late, and `re.split(..., s, maxsplit=1)` is imho the best way, but you could still do it without maxsplit:

```
>>> for i in l:
...   print re.findall("^[^ ]*|[A-Z].*", i)
... 
['Tough', 'Fox']
['Nice', 'White Cat']
['This', 'Dog']
```

Comment: Not the desired output though

Comment: No, no splitting at `Cat` allowed; only between `Nice` and `White Cat`.

Comment: @all my bad. Corrected!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: def split(s):
   ...:     return re.split(r'\W(?=[A-Z])', s, 1)
   ...:

In [3]: l = ["Tough Fox", "Nice White Cat", "This is a lazy Dog" ]

In [4]: for s in l:
   ...:     print(split(s))
   ...:
['Tough', 'Fox']
['Nice', 'White Cat']
['This is a lazy', 'Dog']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.split()` with a limit:

```
 space_split = re.compile(r'\s+(?=[A-Z])')
 result = space_split.split(inputstring, 1)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> space_split = re.compile(r'\s+(?=[A-Z])')
>>> l = ["Tough Fox", "Nice White Cat", "This is a lazy Dog" ]
>>> for i in l:
...     print space_split.split(i, 1)
... 
['Tough', 'Fox']
['Nice', 'White Cat']
['This is a lazy', 'Dog']
```